# COUNTUNIQUEIFS with two criterion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone please help me figure out the right formula for the below problem?

I want a count without"sample"
The right answer is 3 but formula return 4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebq0r.png)

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS('PD01'!B2:B17,'PD01'!C2:C17,"PD01",D2:D17,"NEW",'PD01'!A2:A17,J2)+COUNTUNIQUEIFS('PD01'!B2:B17,'PD01'!C2:C17,"PD01",D2:D17,"",'PD01'!A2:A17,J2)
```

Thanks a lot

Link spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OTLcaJybrTvlWpwVy03a3cUeN1jPL9ZsYa7m8PddZ-U/edit#gid=0

Comment: There is no way to test this with just an image. Please share a link to the sample spreadsheet if you'd like more help.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OTLcaJybrTvlWpwVy03a3cUeN1jPL9ZsYa7m8PddZ-U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=countunique(query(A:D, "Select B where A = date '"&TEXT(F2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C = '"&G2&"' and D matches '^(NEW|)$'", 0))
```